# How to resolve the error - Could not AOT the assembly ... System.Configuration.dll?

Tags: c#, ios, entity-framework, xamarin, system.configuration

I have a Xamarin Forms project with an iOS and UWP project. When building the iOS project I get the following error:

> Could not AOT the assembly
>   '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/xxx.iOS/xxx/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/3-Build/System.Configuration.dll'

The solution also contains a .net-standard 2.0 class library which the Xamarin Forms project references. This class library contains the following Nuget Packages:

- EntityFrameworkCore
- EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
- EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
- Newtonsoft.Json
- System.ComponentModel.Annotations
- MyNugetPackage (Custom Package which has the dependencies you see below)
  [image: MyNugetPackageDependencies]

My Xamarin Forms Project has the following Nuget Packages:

- SimpleInjector
- Xamarin.Forms (4.4.0)
- Xamarin Essentials (1.4)

I have read the following post but they it doesn't resolve my issue:

- [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286404/monotouch-could-not-aot-the-assembly) - I'm not using MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute
- [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114873/could-not-aot-the-assembly-or-you-must-invoke-loadapplication) - I'm not using linking (Set to Don't Link)

I have also looked at all the Nuget Packages but can't see any that depend on System.Configuration. Turning on verbose mode (-v -v -v -v) does not add any more information regarding System.Configuration. How can I get my project to build? If you need any more information feel free to ask.

Comment: Make sure that the version of your IDE is up to date . And you could delete the folder `bin` and `obj` both in iOS and share project .Then clean and rebuild it .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT - Visual Studio Version is 16.4.5 and a full clean and rebuild did not help.

Comment: You could report the issue to official forum: Open your IDE->Help->send feedback->report a problem..

Comment: @RyanGaudion did you find a solution to this problem? I am seeing exactly the same isssue in almost identical circumstances (and, as you said, it only affects iOS).

Comment: Hi Tim, unfortunately I did not find a solution other than using entity Framework Core 2 instead of 3 (which only worked occasionally). I instead opted to learn ASP.net Core and create a Web API for the application